# using multiple named views in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angularjs with ui-router and need a dashboard pattern with this.

I have a menu and I want to open a widget on clicking this button with its content and when I click 2nd button another widget with it's content should be loaded without disturbing 1st one.
[image]

my idea was this.

**Routing**

```
    $stateProvider
        .state("dashboard", {
             abstract:true,
            url: "/",
                 templateUrl:partialDir+"dashbord.html",
                 controller:"dashboardCtrl"
               })
        .state("dashboard.home",{
            url:"home",
                views:{
                'teacher':{
                       //teacher's partial and controller alongwith further     child routes
                    },
                'Student':{
                        //student's partial and controller alongwith further child routes
                    },
   //same for employee
                }
            });
})
```

**DashboardCtrl**

it manages an array against click event.click on teacher in menu will send view="teacher" 
this array is generating against every click correctly but i want something like this....

```
     <ul ng-repeat="view in views|unique:'name'">
     <li><ui-view="{{view.name}}"></ui-view></li>
     </ul>
```

which is not working.

InShort I want to show multiple named views but not at once.wanna show them against click event with separate scope for each widget.

I think I have cleared my app's structure will anyone help n tell me why these named views are not working as I want.Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: More specifically,  what is not working? Nothing shows? Your ui-router logic is good.  Can you provide your dashboardCtrl code?

Comment: $scope.$on('ps-menu-item-state-event', function (evt, data) {
         $scope.views.push({name:data.view});
         
      });//this event is broadcast against menu's click event.and till here array of views is set correctly.i can even see whole array in this section:<ul ng-repeat="view in views|unique:'name'">
     <li><ui-view="{{view.name}}"></ui-view>{{view.name}}</li>
     </ul>/////only problem is named views not working.